# How to implement Kendo UI Custom validator on grid level

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo, kendo-ui-grid, kendo-validator

I have a Kendo UI Grid with is configured for batch editing. What I wish to achieve is a grid level custom validation before the grid's CRUD functions are invoked. So assuming the grid displays a list of employees, and user adds two employees with the same EmployeeID; then on clicking 'Save Changes', the grid should invoke the custom validator rules(say we have a one rule to check whether all the employee id's are unique). Based on the validation result, the grid should decide whether to invoke it's create/update/destroy functions.

I would greatly appreciate if someone can respond to my concern.

My Kendo Grid:

```
<div id="allocGrid" kendo-validator="ctrl.allocationGridValidatorRules" kendo-grid k-options="ctrl.allocationGridOptions(dataItem)"></div>
```

Validation Rules:

```
ctrl.allocationGridValidatorRules = {
        rules: {
            customRule1: function (input) {
                // this rule may check if all the employee Id's in the grid are unique
            }
        },
        messages: {
            customRule1: "Enter a unique Employee Id"
        }
    };
```

I was referring to the below links:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidsalahi/qMRBc/

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing batch edit and u want to check for duplicates I suggest you to use [saveChanges](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-saveChanges) event where u can do your check on *e.sender.dataSource* and stop saving changes if needed

```
saveChanges: function(e) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to save all changes?")) {
       e.preventDefault(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to create the custom validations in the DataSource bound to your grid. For example, you can do something like this:

```
employees = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   schema: {
      model: {
         fields: {
            EmployeeID: {
               validation: {
                  employeeidvalidation: function(input){
                     if(input.is('[name="EmployeeID"]'){
                        //Implement custom validation here...
                     }
                     return true;
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```